# Counting truths in Prolog without built-in functions such as aggregate

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to answer an exercise in Prolog:

"define a predicate same_height(Block1,Block2) which is true if Block1 and Block2 have the same amount of Blocks below them."

- You can assume Block1\=Block2.
- on(X,Y) = Block X is on Block Y.
- is_left_to(X,Y) = Block X & Block Y are on the floor(no blocks underneath them) AND Block X is on the immediate left of Block Y.

I can't use anything besides the very basic operators.
No built-in functions.

This is my current .pl file:

```
on(d,c).
on(c,b).
on(b,a).

on(g,f).
on(f,e).

on(i,h).

adjacent_blocks(Block1,Block2) :-
    (on(Block1,Block2) ; on(Block2,Block1)) , Block1\=Block2.

interior_block(Block) :-
    on(Block,_) , on(_,Block).

above(Block1,Block2) :-
    (on(Block1,Block2)
    ;
    on(Block1,Block3),
    above(Block3,Block2)).

below(X,Y) :-
    above(Y,X).

is_left_to(a,e).
is_left_to(e,h).

left(Block1,Block2) :-
    ((is_left_to(Block1,Block2))
    ;
    (below(X,Block1),(is_left_to(X,Block2)
    ;
    is_left_to(X,Block3),left(Block3,Block2)))
    ;
    (below(Y,Block2),(is_left_to(Block1,Y)
    ;
    is_left_to(Block1,Block3),left(Block3,Y)))
    ;
    (is_left_to(X,Y)
    ;
    is_left_to(X,Block3),left(Block3,Y))).
```

Comment: Ok, so can you be specific? Since you've posted, I take it your code is not working. What exactly is the problem? What debugging have you done? Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: Current code works, I just can't figure how to approach the question I asked above without using built-in functions...

Comment: `same_height(Block1, Block2)` will be true if either (a) neither `Block1` nor `Block2` has a block below it, or (b) both `Block1` and `Block2` have a block below them, and those blocks in turn have the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to count solutions to do this. You can just recur on both blocks. First, let me make a helper predicate for finding out if something is on the floor (due to the oddness of that being a side-note of `is_left_to/2`):

```
on_floor(X) :- is_left_to(X, _) ; is_left_to(_, X).
```

Now consider your base case: they're both on the floor:

```
same_height(X, Y) :- on_floor(X), on_floor(Y).
```

The recursive case is similar: just find out what's underneath X and Y, and ask if they're at the same height. If they are, then X and Y must be at the same height as each other too, one higher than the two blocks beneath them:

```
same_height(X, Y) :-
    on(X, BelowX),
    on(Y, BelowY),
    same_height(BelowX, BelowY).
```

You could also extend this to figure out the height pretty easily:

```
same_height(X, Y, 0) :- on_floor(X), on_floor(Y).
same_height(X, Y, Height1) :-
    on(X, BelowX),
    on(Y, BelowY),
    same_height(BelowX, BelowY, Height0),
    succ(Height0, Height1).
```